# Calculating distances between all possible combinations of lats and longs

Tags: r, latitude-longitude

I can't get the below code to work. I'm trying to calculate the distances between all possible combinations of lats and longs in my data set.

Sample input data I'll use:

```
p <- data.frame(lat=runif(6,-90,90), lon=runif(6,-180,180) );
```

I can't get the below code to work. The distance function doesn't work, so I tried `distm`, but that also gave me an error message. The error message is listed below the code.

```
d <- setNames(do.call(rbind.data.frame, 
                      combn(1:nrow(p), 2, simplify = FALSE)), 
              c('p1','p2'));
d$dist <- sapply(1:nrow(d), function(r){
    distance(p$lat[d$p1[r]], p$lat[d$p2[r]], p$lon[d$p1[r]], p$lon[d$p2[r]])
})

d$dist <- sapply(1:nrow(d), function(r){
    distm(p$lat[d$p1[r]], p$lat[d$p2[r]], p$lon[d$p1[r]], p$lon[d$p2[r]])
})

#> Error in distm(p$lat[d$p1[r]], p$lat[d$p2[r]], p$lon[d$p1[r]], p$lon[d$p2[r]]) : 
#>  unused argument (p$lon[d$p2[r]])
```

Comment: maybe `sapply(combn(nrow(p), 2, simplify = FALSE), function(i){geosphere::distHaversine(p[i[1], 2:1], p[i[2], 2:1])})`

Comment: That seems to have worked, but the values are really large. Are the units in meters? @alistaire

Comment: values returned by distHaversine are in the same units as the r (earth radius) parameter, which is meters by default. They should be big numbers because your sample data have big differences.

Answer (score 8):

`geosphere::distHaversine` (and most of the other distance functions) is vectorized, so you can call it on all the pairs at once. Putting it all into a nice data.frame,

```r
p <- data.frame(lat = runif(6, -90, 90), 
                lon = runif(6, -180, 180))

# get row indices of pairs
row_pairs <- combn(nrow(p), 2)

# make data.frame of pairs
df_dist <- cbind(x = p[row_pairs[1,],], 
                 y = p[row_pairs[2,],])
# add distance column by calling distHaversine (vectorized) on each pair
df_dist$dist <- geosphere::distHaversine(df_dist[2:1], df_dist[4:3])

df_dist
#>          x.lat      x.lon      y.lat      y.lon     dist
#> 1   -10.281070 -156.30519  -7.027720 -104.76897  5677699
#> 1.1 -10.281070 -156.30519 -51.142344 -100.99517  6750255
#> 1.2 -10.281070 -156.30519  -3.979805 -141.43436  1785251
#> 1.3 -10.281070 -156.30519 -21.239130  -65.97719  9639637
#> 1.4 -10.281070 -156.30519  66.292704 -154.52851  8525401
#> 2    -7.027720 -104.76897 -51.142344 -100.99517  4923176
#> 2.1  -7.027720 -104.76897  -3.979805 -141.43436  4075742
#> 2.2  -7.027720 -104.76897 -21.239130  -65.97719  4459657
#> 2.3  -7.027720 -104.76897  66.292704 -154.52851  9085777
#> 3   -51.142344 -100.99517  -3.979805 -141.43436  6452943
#> 3.1 -51.142344 -100.99517 -21.239130  -65.97719  4502520
#> 3.2 -51.142344 -100.99517  66.292704 -154.52851 13833468
#> 4    -3.979805 -141.43436 -21.239130  -65.97719  8350236
#> 4.1  -3.979805 -141.43436  66.292704 -154.52851  7893225
#> 5   -21.239130  -65.97719  66.292704 -154.52851 12111227
```

Alternatively, you can use `geosphere::distm`, which gives you a distance matrix, which contains the same data in a different format:

```r
geosphere::distm(p[, 2:1])
#>         [,1]    [,2]     [,3]    [,4]     [,5]     [,6]
#> [1,]       0 5677699  6750255 1785251  9639637  8525401
#> [2,] 5677699       0  4923176 4075742  4459657  9085777
#> [3,] 6750255 4923176        0 6452943  4502520 13833468
#> [4,] 1785251 4075742  6452943       0  8350236  7893225
#> [5,] 9639637 4459657  4502520 8350236        0 12111227
#> [6,] 8525401 9085777 13833468 7893225 12111227        0
```

As described by `?distHaversine`, distances are in meters. Convert as you like. Also note that geosphere's functions take lon/lat, not lat/lon, so the columns need to be reversed to work.

Comment: That worked perfect. I started with an actual data frame from a csv, so I had to rename "p" to that data frame. Next question: I only want to focus on distances <= 1320'. Is there an easy way to exclude all values >1320'? and then recreate the data frame?

Comment: So for example I have x.well.label and y.well.label. But I only want to keep the pairs that are <=1320' from each other @alistaire

Comment: So for every x.well.label I only want to keep the y.well.label's within 1320'

 x.Well.Label    x.lat     x.lon                y.Well.Label    y.lat     y.lon         dist
1                   ALLEN L A  27-1 32.61039 -92.86851          AULDS 29-32-5 HC 1 32.60133 -92.70121 15721.258274
1.1                 ALLEN L A  27-1 32.61039 -92.86851                BARNETT 22-1 32.62133 -92.76106 10148.060378
1.2                 ALLEN L A  27-1 32.61039 -92.86851             BARTLETT V H 26 32.52477 -92.75865 14037.173260

Comment: Just subset after the fact, e.g. `p2 <- p[p$distance <= 1320, ]`

Comment: That didn't seem to work. It gives me a data table with 0 rows...not sure what I did wrong @alistaire

Comment: Edit with a version that reproduces the problem?